# Chart.js : How to fill the area under the line to a certain point?

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, chart.js, linechart

I created a line chart using the `chart.js` library and filled the area under the line.

The problem that I'm having is the fill under the line does not stop at the last plotted point on the graph. The fill under the curve should stop when the line stops but it keeps going. Is there are a way to specify the fill area so it doesn't fill past the line/last plotted point?

I've looked at the documentation and found a fill property but it's not fixing the problem. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the chart border or gridlines.

Comment: What does your chart object/code look like?

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to post the code.

Comment: This is because you have more data than your labels. Make sure both of your `lables` and `data` array's lengths are equal.

Comment: That worked. I was spending hours messing with the border and grid lines but it turns out it was something different. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could have added a sample graph to demonstrate your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In the `dataset` options, set `fill: '-1'`